# How to find angles of a semicircle-embedded pentagon

Tags: geometry

I know this question seems too easy to post it here (it is for 9th graders in India) but somehow I had to skip classes at school and couldn't attend geometry and now I am stuck with a question I couldn't solve

> In the given semicircle; ABCDE is a cycle? pentagon in which AB is diameter. Find $\angle C + \angle E$.
> [image]

This is the exact question which was printed and I think cycle? might be mistyped so I have kept it open for interpretations.
Obviously, this has to be solved by using normal circle theorems and not some advanced ones that you just do it in a single step. Suprisingly this is an mcq, yet, if it comes in my tomorrow's maths exam, I couldn't write.

Please help, I will be grateful!

#### APPENDIX:

The theorems and results we have been taught and are expected to use are as follows:

###### Quadrilaterals:-

Opposite sides of a parallelogram are equal. 
Opposite angles of a parallelogram are equal. 
Consecutive angles of a parallelogram are supplementary.
Diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.
All angles of a rectangle are right angles.
Diagonals of a rectangle are equal and bisect each other.
All angles of a square are right angles.
Diagonals of a square are equal and bisect each other at right angles.
Opposite sides of a rhombus are equal.
Opposite angles of a rhombus are equal.
Diagonals of a rhombus bisect each other at right angles.
In a trapezium, the sum of any pair of opposite angles is 180.
The diagonals of an isosceles trapezium are equal and bisect each other.

###### Circles:-

Equal chords of a circle subtend equal angles at the center. 
If the angles subtended by two chords of a circle at the center are equal, then the chords are equal.
The perpendicular from the center of a circle to a chord bisects the chord.
There is one and only one circle passing through three non-collinear points.
Equal chords of a circle are equidistant from the center.
Angles in the same segment of a circle are equal.
The angle subtended by an arc at the center is double the angle subtended by it at any point on the remaining part of the circle.
The opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral are supplementary.
If a line segment joining two points subtends equal angles at two other points lying on the same side of the line containing the segment, the four points lie on a circle.

###### Triangles (just in case):-

The sum of all the three interior angles of a triangle is 180 degrees. 
The base angles of an isosceles triangle are congruent. 
The measure of the exterior angle of a triangle is equal to the sum of the corresponding interior angles. 
Midpoint and converse of midpoint theorems 
All the five congruencies, SSS, SAS, AAS, ASA, RHS 
Euclid's axioms and 5 postulates

Comment: "The opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral are supplementary" + The special case of "Angles in the same segment of a circle are equal" when the segment is a diameter.

Comment: @achillehui I dont feel that this can be turned into a cyclic quadrilateral?? can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: $ABCD$ and $ABDE$ are cyclic quadrilaterals.

Comment: @CuckooBeats join any diagonal. Then the quadrilateral you find yourself with is cyclic.

Comment: thank you so much, I think I might have been confused with the semicircle, thank you so much once again --- i will post the solution and close it as soon as I find the solution

Comment: and thanks to @insipidintegrator for editing the question :)

Comment: @achillehui i got it now it was soo simple......thank you so much for your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So again thanks to @achillehui and @insipidintegrator for their hints!

Construction:- join BD and AD
Proof:- quadrilaterals ADCB and AEDB are cyclic 
 Let <A be a and <B be b. Then angles <EDB and <ADC are 180-a and 180-b respectively 
But angle ADB is 90 degrees. 
Hence angles EDA and BDC are 90-a and 90-b respectively. 
In pentagon AEDCB, sum of all interior angles = 540 
Sum of angles= a + <E + (90-a + 90 + 90-b) + <C + b = 540 
Or, <E + <C + 270 = 540 
Or, <C + <E = 270

Comment: Slightly more directly, $\angle DEA = 1/2 \angle DOA$, but note that we're using the "exterior" angle (not the one that's$ <180^\circ$) and likewise $\angle DCB = 1/2 \angle DOB$. So $ \angle DEA + \angle DCB = 1/2 ( \angle DOA + \angle DOB ) = 1/2 ( 360^\circ + 180^\circ) = 270^\circ$.

Comment: @CalvinLin thank you, this is much easier

Answer (score 0):

## This answer is wrong! The equation is also correct in case the figure is not half a regular octagon.

I'd like to request to redraw the image, showing the points $C$, $D$ and $E$ in more random positions in order to avoid this misunderstanding.

Previous answer:

> The main point is:
>
> > The sum of all the three interior angles of a triangle is 180 degrees.
> > Your image shows the half of a regular octagon, and you want to know the sum of two of its angles. By drawing a line segment from every point of a regular octagon to the centre, you get eight triangles, each of them having $180°$ as the sum of its angles. The sum of the angles of your octagon then equals:

> $$8 \times 180° - 360°$$

> (subtracting $360°$ means that you subtract the angles in the centre.)

> So, all eigth angles together make $1080°$, and the sum of two them equals $2 \times \frac{1080°}{8} = 270°$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the figure must be a regular octagon, which need not be the case. (EG Figure need not be drawn to scale.)

Comment: @CalvinLin: in case it's not a regular octagon, the question is unsolvable.

Comment: No it's not. The answer is constant regardless of where the points E, D, C are (as long as they are in that order). See OP's solution, which doesn't assume regular octagon.

Comment: @CalvinLin: you are right (I checked with Geogebra). I've updated my answer accordingly.